# Cannot display image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had Image control and I added code to display images But there is not any image displayed

ASPX:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div dir='<%= sDirection %>'>
        <div  id="ContentImage" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

C#:

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            string Sql = "Select Image From AboutUsData Where Id=@Id";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, con);
            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Id", Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()));
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read() && dr != null)
            {



                Image2.ImageUrl = dr["Image"].ToString();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems you're setting the `ImageUrl` property for `Image1` instead of `Image2`.

Also, you have to make sure that the `ImageUrl` path returned actually maps to an image on the server (wether relative or absolute). To put an example, if your code renders this image:

```
<img src="images/photo.gif" alt="my photo2" />
```

but there is no image in `images/photo.gif`, because its actually located in `../images/photo.gif` (the images directory sits elsewhere) then no image will be displayed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any exception thrown when running DB command? Does dr["Image"] contain some value? What about CSS, ContentImage maybe hiding div container?